# spring cloud zuul can not works with a simple example code

Tags: spring-cloud, netflix-zuul

I'm newbie to Spring Cloud. Following the example of [Start Guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/routing-and-filtering/). I'm stuck at Zuul example.

With a request to zuul, my client app not receive any request from zuul and get  405(Method not allowed) to my browser.
But test without zuul, the client app can response success.

Simple code as this:
Zuul Server:

```
@EnableZuulProxy
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyZuulApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyZuulApp.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public SimpleFilter simpleFilter() {
        return new SimpleFilter();
    }

}
```

Configuration:

```
##Zuul routes. Here for /student path, we are routing to localhost:8090 with extra path after that.
zuul.routes.book_app.url=http://localhost:8090
#zuul.routes.book_app=/book_app/**

##Ribbon is auto integrated with Zuul and for this exercise we are not using that.
ribbon.eureka.enabled=false

##Will start the gateway server @8080
server.port=8083

logging.level.org.springframework.web=DEBUG
```

Client App:

```
@RestController
@SpringBootApplication
public class BookApp {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/available")
    public String available() {
        System.out.println("get abailable - ");

        return "Spring in Action";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/checked-out")
    public String checkedOut() {
        return "Spring Boot in Action";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(BookApp.class, args);
    }
}
```

Configuration:

```
spring.application.name=book_app

server.port=8090

logging.level.org.springframework.web=DEBUG
```

Full code has organized at [Github](https://github.com/LoranceChen/spring-cloud-practice).
See my-zuul and book-app for that situation.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downloaded your code and run locally and it worked as expected.

Your Zuul application.properties

```
  zuul.routes.book_app.url=http://localhost:8090
  server.port=8083
```

Since your book application name is book_app.Zuul will proxy request to **/book_app**.So you have to send requests like this: http://localhost:8083/book_app/checked-out/.

Comment: really annoying why I'm encounter 405. I will checkout to another PC to verify my code again. Thanks for your download and give a try!

Comment: can you share your url request and what tool are you testing with?

Comment: hi, my URL test with http://localhost:8083/book_app/available and http://localhost:8090/available . The latter is work fine but the former give me a 405 response. Tested both chrome and postman with get method.

Comment: Oh, MGD. I find where is mess. Shadowsocks agent swallow my 8090 port somehow. :- ( The problem take more then 5 hours totally.